# Need help combining 2 functions if the players reset count is >=4

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a clicker game setup. I want when the (reset count) rebirth count >= 4 for this strengthexp function to be added to it.

```
 var cookies = 0;
var Strength = 1;

function cookieClick(){
cookies = cookies + Strength;
document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};
```

I have tried just doing

Click Me!

to run 2 functions then i put a if statement in the strengthexp for if rebirths>=4  but that didnt work. the button at first jsut adds to a counter that u can use those points to buy stuff. after 4 game resets i want it to also add 1 exp to a different counter .

This is what i tried for the function(i'll add the variables in my code i reverted it to):

```
function Strengthexp() {
    if (StrengthCexp < NextMaxStrengthExp && rebirths>=4 ) {
      StrengthCexp = StrengthCexp + 1;
     document.getElementById("StrengthCexp").innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
} else {
    Strengthlv = Strengthlv + 1
    StrengthCexp = 0
    Strength = Strength + 1
    NextMaxStrengthExp = NextMaxStrengthExp * 1.5;
    document.getElementById('StrengthMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxStrengthExp;
    document.getElementById('Strengthlv').innerHTML = Strengthlv;
    document.getElementById('StrengthCexp').innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
    document.getElementById('Strength').innerHTML = Strength;
```

HTML code:

```
   </style>
            <span id="cookies">0</span>
            <br />
            <span id="rebirths">0</span>
            <br />
            <button onclick="cookieClick()">Click Me!</button>
            <br />
            Cost: 10mp <button id="BigClickBtn" 
onclick="Bigclick()">BigClick</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="antCost">10</span> <button onclick="buyAnt()" 
id="antCostBtn" >Buy Ant</button> <span id="ants">0</span>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button onclick="buyCat()" 
id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button> <span id="cats">0</span>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button onclick="buyDog()" 
id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button> <span id="dogs">0</span>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button 
onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button> <span 
id="humans">0</span>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">10</span> <button 
onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn">Rebirth</button>
            <br />
            Hp:<span id="HitPoints">0</span> Mp:<span 
id="ManaPoints">0</span> 
            <br />
            Strength: Lv <span id="Strengthlv">1</span> <span 
id="StrengthCexp">0</span> / <span id="StrengthMexp">100</span>
```

Javascript functions for cookieclick/strengthexp(basiaclly the same as above):

```
var cookies = 0;
var Strength = 1;

function cookieClick(){
cookies = cookies + Strength;
 document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

var Strengthlv = 1;
var StrengthCexp = 0;
var StrengthMexp = 100;
var NextMaxStrengthExp = StrengthMexp;


function Strengthexp() {
    if (StrengthCexp < NextMaxStrengthExp ) {
       StrengthCexp = StrengthCexp + 1;
        document.getElementById("StrengthCexp").innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
   } else {
      Strengthlv = Strengthlv + 1
      StrengthCexp = 0
      Strength = Strength + 1
      NextMaxStrengthExp = NextMaxStrengthExp * 1.5;
      document.getElementById('StrengthMexp').innerHTML = 
   NextMaxStrengthExp;
      document.getElementById('Strengthlv').innerHTML = Strengthlv;
      document.getElementById('StrengthCexp').innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
      document.getElementById('Strength').innerHTML = Strength;


    }

}
```

(rebirth function for refrence to what rebirth does)

```
var rebirths = 0;
var HitPoints = 0;
var ManaPoints = 0;
var SkillPoints = 0;
var NextRebirthCost = rebirthCost;

function buyRebirth(){
var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,rebirths));     
if(cookies >= rebirthCost && rebirths < 1){                                   
     rebirths = rebirths + 1;                                   /
    cookies = 0;
    HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
    ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
    SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
    NextRebirthCost = Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
    document.getElementById('rebirths').innerHTML = rebirths;  
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
     document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
    document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = NextRebirthCost;
    document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;
};
   if (cookies >= rebirthCost)
        if (rebirths >= 1) {
            cookies = 0;
            rebirths = rebirths + 1;
            SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
            NextRebirthCost = Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
            document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
            document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = 
NextRebirthCost;
            document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
            document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;

        }
};
```

I expect after rebirths is >= 4 that the cookie click function will start adding 1 to strengthcexp everytime you the "Click Me!"button. Not before that because this is a unlock. But the actual output is i can't get the functions to combine/ work together to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work

```
<button onclick="cookieClick(); Strengthexp()">Click Me!</button>
```

then i added  this with my scripts and added that if statement to my strengthup

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Skills.js"></script>
```

I forgot that you need to do this if you want a function from a different js to work.